# Firebase storage could not upload file

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-console

I am new to Firebase and started with android app and a web app linked to same project in Firebase. I would like to add data(images, videos etc.) in the firebase storage and want to access and CRUD from web and mobile app.

I cannot add files to Firebase. Clicking on `Upload File` is not opening a dialog and eventually could not choose a file from my local.

I could see console 404 server responses when I log in to Firebase(Not specifically in storage). Not sure what is blocking me to upload a file to firebase storage.

[image: Screenshot of console errors]

Any help with this is appreciated.
Thank you

**ERROR**

> error 1:
>   gstatic.com/*/pantheon/*/ss/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.-sf…va/c‌om/google/d‌​evelopers/console/mobilesdk_web/console/styles/shared/icons
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>   error error-2:
>   gstatic.com/*/pantheon/*/ss/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.-sf…va/co‌m/google/d‌​evelopers/console/mobilesdk_web/console/styles/shared/layout
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>   Error 3 :
>   gstatic.com/*/pantheon/*/ss/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.-sf…va/c‌​om/google/developers/console/mobilesdk_web/console/styles/shared/icons
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Can you add the error message and URL to your question as text?

Comment: Voted to move to DBA

Comment: Hi Frank, here they are. Please have a look:
error 1: gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/ss/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.-sf…va/c‌om/google/developers/console/mobilesdk_web/console/styles/shared/icons
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () error error-2:
gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/ss/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.-sf…va/co‌m/google/developers/console/mobilesdk_web/console/styles/shared/layout 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Error 3 :

https://www.gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/ss/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.-sf…va/com/google/developers/console/mobilesdk_web/console/styles/shared/icons Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: May be its an issue with my chrome. I just checked with IE and it worked fine.